# Points on hyperelliptic curves coming from an orbit of an algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-curves

Consider a hyperelliptic curve $C_F$ defined over $\mathbb{P}(1,1,g+1)$ by the equation

$$\displaystyle C_F: z^2 = F(x,y),$$

where $F \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is a non-singular binary form of degree $2g+2$.

It is conjectured (and proved by Caporaso, Harris, and Mazur under the Bombieri-Lang conjecture) that the number of rational points on $C_F$ is *uniformly bounded* when $g \geq 2$ in the sense that there exists a number $N(g)$ depending only on $g \geq 2$ such that for all such $F$, we have $|C_F(\mathbb{Q})| \leq N(g)$. Stoll proved such a bound with the extra condition that the rank $r$ of the Mordell-Weil group of the Jacobian of $C_F$ satisfies $r \leq g-3$.

My question concerns restricting $(x,y)$ to an orbit of a small (but infinite) subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Indeed, the simplest such example would be the subgroup $G_M$ generated by some $M \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of infinite order.

For such a group $G$, put $G_0$ for the orbit of $(1,0)$ under $G$. One can then form the counting function

$$S(F, G) = \# \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \cap G_0: \text{there exists } z \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ s.t. } z^2 = F(x,y)\}.$$

Clearly, $S(F,G) \leq |C_F(\mathbb{Q})|$, hence finite when $g \geq 2$.

My question is, when $G = G_M$ for some $M \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, can one show that $S(F,G_M)$ is uniformly bounded in terms of $M,g$?

Comment: One case of this would be integral points, but I am not aware of an unconditional uniform bound in this situation.

Comment: @MichaelStoll Indeed, a uniform bound for integral points would imply a uniform bound for rational points, as you can clear denominators at the cost of changing the equation of the curve.

Comment: @WillSawin You are right, of course --- in this special case, both questions are equivalent.